# Increase performance of cassandra

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, database-performance, database-tuning

If I increase the size of sstables, performance will be perfect, please anyone can list me all key parameters i want to edit it to increase performance of cassandra. i think exists a lot off parameters want to change it.

I tried to edit cassandra-env.sh to increase number of cores and heap size

```
system_memory_in_mb="50000"
system_cpu_cores="16"
```

I don't have any errors, but I have a large latency in write.

I want to know what's the main parameters I can edit to have best performance

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra many things need to tune to get high performance based on application behaviour and nature. you can tune JVM parameters upto a certain limit and can get better performance for highly write intensive application. Also,you can select or change compaction strategy.

Comment: yes exactly, for me i need especialy what's this parameters you need to edit it without JVM parameters beacause i already modify it but i don't notice the difference in write performance, please if you have an idea about this parameters help me and thanks in advance !!!